# Odoo 16 Inherit template and replace 1 field

Tags: xml, inheritance, qweb, odoo-16

I have installed an addon to Odoo 16 Ent, which creates a separate quote number rather than just the standard sales ref number, however on the customer preview, it still shows "Quotation #" and then the sales order number.
I have inherited the sale order report and added the code:

[image: screenshot1]

```
<data inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
<h2 class="mt-4">
<span t-if="doc.state in ['draft','sent']">t-field="doc.quotation_number"</span>
</h2>
</data>
```

When I go to the customer preview it still shows the sale order number, and then, when I print the quotation to PDF, it shows the field as printed text as per image.
I guess I need to replace the original field with the quotation-number field, but I've searched everywhere and can't find how to do this.
I'm at the beginning of my coding journey, so please feel free to explain to me like I'm 5.

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 0):

To inherit the sale order report as below:

```
<template id="report_saleorder_document_inherit_quotation_number" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
    <xpath expr="//span[@t-field='doc.name']" position="replace">
        <span t-if="doc.state in ['draft','sent']" t-field="doc.quotation_number"/>
        <span t-else="" t-field="doc.name"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

The customer preview has a template which you can inherit and change it separately as below:

```
 <template id="portal_my_quotations_inherit"  inherit_id="sale.portal_my_quotations">
    <xpath expr="//t[@t-out='quotation.name']" position="replace">
        <t t-out="quotation.quotation_number"/>
    </xpath>
 </template>
```